# Can't debug a Windows Phone crash

Tags: windows-phone

I have a MVVM application that is navigating between pages. At a certain moment, the app starts to crash when navigating to page X, and the crash isn't calling the UnhandledExceptionHandler nor the NavigationFailedHandler. If I place message boxes after the constructor or at the beginning of the overrided OnNavigatedTo method, it is just -not- hit, but for a non-crashing scenario, they are hit.

The app is just closing, no exception nowhere.

I think I've tried eveything I know about how to debug this crash on user's phone, without success.

[EDIT] I'm searching for deadlocks, stack overflows, etc.

Comment: do you use any mvvm frameworks (mvvm light or caliburn micro)?

Comment: Hum, it's on the `MVVM` template that comes with `Visual Studio`. Models are almost empty, it comes with a minimal set of pages. The crash comes from `BackgroundTransferService`, that is strangely crashing when some `BackgroundTransferRequest` are switching from transferring to WaitingForX.

Comment: You should update your question if the issue now relates to `BackgroundTransferService`

Comment: What I'd like is to see other within the next days or years sharing their experiences on this post so we can empirically see if exceptions are sometime lost without being catched. I won't post about BackgroundTransferService as the documentation isn't accurate, and all I get when questioning about BTS are answers from MVPs copy-pasting me this documentation.